# Process won't exit when UseShellExecute = false, but exits when UseShellExecute = true

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

I run a process from a asp.net core application:

```
bool createShell = true;
//generate output pdf
using var pdfGeneratorProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        UseShellExecute = createShell,
        CreateNoWindow = createShell,
        RedirectStandardError = !createShell,
        RedirectStandardOutput = !createShell,
        WorkingDirectory = dir,
        FileName = "java",
        Arguments = $"-cp \"fop-2.0.jar;lib/*\"; FOPLocalPDFGenerator {rendererFile} {inputFile} {outputFile}"
    }
};
_logger.LogInformation("{CMD}", $"{pdfGeneratorProcess.StartInfo.FileName} {pdfGeneratorProcess.StartInfo.Arguments}");
pdfGeneratorProcess.Start();
```

When createShell is true, the process writes some PDF file and exits. When I set it to false, it runs with the same StandardOutput and StandardError it seems, but never finishes and the PDF file is empty.

**Why does the process hang when there is no console window visible?**

Comment: `CreateNoWindow = !createShell`?

Answer (score 0):

When [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput) is true, the process's output is redirected to [Process.StandardOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput).

But in the OP code the `Process.StandardOutput` isn't read and the buffer fills up to its limit. When the limit is reached, the process can't write `Process.StandardOutput` and wait some free space.

Same story with [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror) and [Process.StandardError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror)

One solution is to set `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` and `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError` to false.

Other solution if you want the output, you can redirect the output to other stream. See this example where the output is redirected to a file :

```cs
void Redirect(StreamReader output, StreamWriter to)
{
    string textLine;
    while ((textLine = output.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        to.WriteLine(textLine);
    }
}

bool createShell = true;
//generate output pdf
using var pdfGeneratorProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        UseShellExecute = createShell,
        CreateNoWindow = !createShell, // I inversed the condition
        RedirectStandardError = !createShell,
        RedirectStandardOutput = !createShell,
        WorkingDirectory = dir,
        FileName = "java",
        Arguments = $"-cp \"fop-2.0.jar;lib/*\"; FOPLocalPDFGenerator {rendererFile} {inputFile} {outputFile}"
    }
};
_logger.LogInformation("{CMD}", $"{pdfGeneratorProcess.StartInfo.FileName} {pdfGeneratorProcess.StartInfo.Arguments}");
pdfGeneratorProcess.Start();

using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"C:\Temp\log.txt"))
{
    var standardOutputThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Redirect(pdfGeneratorProcess.StandardOutput, writer)));
    var errorOutputThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Redirect(pdfGeneratorProcess.StandardError, writer)));
    standardOutputThread.Start();
    errorOutputThread.Start();
    standardOutputThread.Join();
    errorOutputThread.Join();
}

pdfGeneratorProcess.WaitForExit();
```